# How to remove Bootstrap from .NET Core Template

Tags: vue.js, .net-core

Creating a SPA application from the templates provided by the dotnet CLI using (in my case)

```
dotnet new vue
```

([detailed instructions here](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet/1383/modern-web-dev-aspnet-core-webpack-vuejs))

will create a template application that utilizes Bootstrap 3. I want to replace Bootstrap with [Element](http://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/installation), but I cannot figure out how to remove Bootstrap, which is included in the Webpack vendor.js and vendor.css files.

I've tried removing all references to Bootstrap as well as the npm package and running:

```
webpack --config webpack.config.js
webpack --config webpack.config.vendor.js
```

But that didn't remove Bootstrap from the vendor files. I also want to add Element to the Webpack build.

Comment: I'm in the same situation, do you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer only for reference, `Boostrap` and others vendor files are registered under the vendor entry in the file `webpack.config.vendor.js`, and whit this information, when the project is started, webpack generates a `manifiest.json`, that contains the vendors that are going to be included in vendor files (`vendor.css, vendor.js`).

If you want to change this files is necessary update the file `webpack.config.vendor.js` and delete the `dist` folder under `wwwroot`, whit this, the file is regenerated and the vendor files updated.

Can be necessary restart de application in debug mode 2 times (F5).